# Why does my logging not work in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am trying to add a logging handler in Python 3 this way:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 14 2017, 22:51:06) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging
>>> 
>>> logger = logging.getLogger()
>>> handler = logging.StreamHandler()
>>> handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
>>> logger.addHandler(handler)
>>> 
>>> logging.info("my info")
>>> logging.warning("my warning")
my warning
```

I specified loglevel as `INFO`. Why does `logging.info("my info")` output nothing?

Comment: If you are just wanting logging to a single handler, you can use [`logging.basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

because you [need](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) to set `logger` lever as well.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
# here
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

output:

```
>>> logging.info("my info")
my info
>>> logging.warning("my warning")
my warning
```

Answer (score 2):

Loggers have levels as well as handlers. The [default level](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) is warn so your info is ignored.

To get your example to work, include `logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)`.

Comment: This is not enough. You also need `logging.basicConfig()` before `logger = logging.getLogger()`

Comment: @flowfelis , it is enough. You don't need to call `basicConfig()` if you are doing the config manually as OP is in their question.

Comment: if this code is what we are talking about:
`import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.info('hello world!')`
Then it doesn't work.

Comment: @flowfelis it's a good thing that's not the code we're talking about then. The question was why the OP's message wasn't being logged in their code.

Answer (score -1):

**This works:**

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.info('hello world!')
```

**Or this also works:**

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.info('hello world!')
```

**This DOES NOT work:**

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.info('hello world!')
```